# Setting up .NET 4.0 Environment

Tags: razor, web

I have got a situation on the server where we are running applications that support asp.net version 1.0 and 2.0. I have recently developed an application in asp.net 4.0 using MVC (Razor Engine).

I am wondering if I install asp.net 4.0 on the server, would that affect the other websites that are already running?

If somebody could advise me on that would I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

no it shouldn't just be sure, that in IIS configuration you set the right application pools. You can set a different app pool for every aspx website/application.

Each pool can be then set up for different .NET version.

Answer (score 0):

nope if by applications you mean websites (you mentioned mvc) then you can configure in the app pool for each site seperatly on which framework they should run in IIS. If you are refering to windows desktop applications you can define the runtime environment when building the application in Visual studio.